# What are the rules of precedence in resolving the method overloading in C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, overloading, overload-resolution

I'm writing a serializer in which I want to make use of method overloads extensively, to serialize objects of types deriving from `IEnumerable<T>`, `IDictionary<K,V>` and so on.

I also intend to use `dynamic` keyword to let CLR choose the correct overload based on the runtime type of the object to be serialized.

Have a look at this code snippet:

```
void Serialize<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
  Console.WriteLine("IDictionary<TKey, TValue>");
}

void Serialize<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> items)
{
  Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>");
}

void Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable<T>");
}
```

And I want to do this:

```
void CallSerialize(object obj)
{
   Serialize(obj as dynamic); //let the CLR resolve it at runtime.
}
```

Now based on the runtime-type of `obj`, the correct overload will be called. For example,

```
//Test code
CallSerialize(new List<int>()); //prints IEnumerable<T>
```

In this case, the third overload is called and the rationale is pretty much straightforward : that is only the viable option.

However, if I do this:

```
CallSerialize(new Dictionary<int,int>()); //prints IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

It calls the first overload. I don't exactly understand this. Why does it resolve to the first overload **when all three overloads are viable options**?

In fact, if I remove the first one, the second overload is called, and if I remove the first and second overload, then the third overload is called.

What are the rules of precedence in resolving the method overloading?

Comment: Most inherited type ? `IDictionary<T, K>` is more derived than `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, K>>` which is more derived than `IEnumerable<T>`. That's just a guess but it would seem logic(at least to me).

Comment: You don't need `dynamic` to let the compiler do overload resolution. In fact, `dynamic` skips compile time resolution and does it at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

The rules for resolving method overloads will try to pick the method header with the most specific type match. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx) you can read more about overload resolution and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(v=vs.71).aspx) I think is your case.

From MSDN:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument types {A1, A2, ..., AN} and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types {P1, P2, ..., PN} and {Q1, Q2, ..., QN}, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from AX to PX is not worse than the implicit conversion from AX to QX, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from AX to PX is better than the conversion from >AX to QX.
>
> When performing this evaluation, if MP or MQ is applicable in its expanded form, then PX or QX refers to a parameter in the expanded form of the parameter list.

Comment: Those links are a bit outdated. You can get the latest spec from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552. Look for section 7.5.3.